# Theoretical reasoning for PCA effectiveness

Tags: pca, normality-assumption, anomaly-detection

> The effectiveness of Principal component analysis in detecting process abnormalities requires that the process data to follow a Gaussian distribution

This is what I read over a thread. Can anyone explain why process data need to follow a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "process data" and "abnormalities?" You can perform principal component analysis on data that does NOT follow a Gaussian distribution. You only need the data to be linearly related--it doesn't have to be normally distributed.

Comment: @AJV Process data = Data generated from some process (Say Ammonia production)
Abnormalities = Data points which the not per the expectation....
Can you please elaborate why the data need to have linear relation? Can't we apply if there is any higher order relation between the data?

Comment: You can apply it on higher-order variables, but it will get more difficult to interpret. And using interaction terms would make it even worse. PCA is based on the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. Since it is based on the covariance matrix, it is already considering the interaction of the variables, since covariance is in some way a measurement of interaction. So if you manually introduce interaction terms, then the covariance matrix will be showing the interaction of the interaction between terms. What does that mean? Very difficult to say.

Comment: Can you link to the thread that says this?

Comment: Related: [PCA of non-Gaussian data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32105/7290).

Answer (score 1):

In general, Gaussian data are neither necessary nor sufficient for successful PCA-based anomaly detection.

As described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259806/anomaly-detection-using-pca-reconstruction-error/260040#260040), PCA-based anomaly detection identifies a point as anomalous if its PCA reconstruction error exceeds a chosen threshold. The reconstruction error is typically defined as the squared Euclidean distance between the point and its projection onto a linear subspace fit by PCA (which is a $k$-dimensional plane). For this procedure to succeed, anomalies must therefore lie further from this plane than 'regular' data, with high probability.

Notice that Gaussian data aren't required. For example, imagine a 3d space where the regular data are distributed arbitrarily over a 2d plane, and anomalies are distributed diffusely over all 3 dimensions. The data aren't Gaussian, but the anomaly detection procedure above will work well (provided we choose a good threshold, and the PCA training set isn't too heavily contaminated by anomalies so the 2d plane is properly identified).

On the other hand, notice that 'in-plane' anomalies can't be detected. This is because the PCA reconstruction error is small for all points lying near the plane, regardless of how far they're perturbed *along* the plane (as illustrated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259806/anomaly-detection-using-pca-reconstruction-error/260040#260040)). This implies that anomaly detection might not succeed, even if the data are Gaussian. For example, imagine that regular data are drawn from a 3d Gaussian distribution with small variance along one direction, so they're concentrated near a 2d plane. Suppose that anomalies are distributed around the same plane, but can lie arbitrarily far from the regular data. E.g. they might be Gaussian too, but have enormous variance along the plane. PCA-based anomaly detection will fail in this case.